# 自作ハッシュテーブルが期待通りに動いていない

Tags: c++

連結リストを要素に持つ配列のハッシュテーブルを作ったつもりです。今回の目的は、そのハッシュテーブルにaddItemでデータを追加して、displayTableでそのハッシュテーブルの内容を返すような関数作りです。このプログラムを実行すると０が返ってこず、プログラムが停止してします。いろいろ試した結果、おそらく問題はdisplayTableメソッドの内のwhile loopまたはLink* temp = array[i]->getHead()だと思います。わかる方よろしくお願いします。

**HashList.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;

class Link
{
private:
    string value;
    Link* next;
public:
    Link(string value, Link* next = nullptr){this->value = value; next = nullptr;}
    ~Link(){}
    string getValue(){return value;}
    Link* getNext(){return next;}
    void setNext(Link* next){this->next = next;}
};

class List
{
private:
    Link* head;
public:
    List(){head = nullptr;}
    void addHead(string value)
    {
        Link* temp = new Link(value, head);
        temp->getNext();
        head = temp;
    }
    Link* getHead(){return head;}

};


class HashList {
private:
    int arraySize;
    List** array;
public:
    HashList(){
        arraySize = 7;
        array = new List*[arraySize];
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new List;
        }
    }

    HashList(int size)
    {
        if(size < 7)
        {
            size = 7;
        }
        arraySize = size;

        array = new List*[arraySize];
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new List;
        }
    }

    int hash(string value)
    {
        int hashValue = 0;

        //figure out the index
        for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
        {
            hashValue *= 128;
            hashValue += value[i];
            hashValue %= arraySize;
        }

        //return the index
        return hashValue;
    }


    void addItem(string value)
    {
        array[hash(value)]->addHead(value);
    }

    string displayTable()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        string output;

        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            Link* temp = array[i]->getHead();

            if(temp == nullptr)
            {
                ss << "_empty_";
            }

            while(temp != nullptr)
            {
                ss << temp->getValue() << " ";
                temp = temp->getNext();
            }

            ss << "\n";

        }

        output = ss.str();

        return output;
    }

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HashList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HashList test;

    test.addItem("Hello");
　　test.addItem("Hello");
    cout << test.displayTable() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Link(string value, Link* next = nullptr){this->value = value; next = nullptr;}
```

ここの `next = nullptr` は無意味です。こうしたかったでしょ：

```
Link(string value, Link* next = nullptr){this->value = value; this->next = next;}
```

Comment: ここのthisが抜けてたのですね。しょうもないミスしてごめんなさい。ついでに連結リストを要素に持つ配列のハッシュテーブルはこれで合っているでしょうか。自分なりに考えて作ってみたのですが、あっているかどうか不安が残っています。

Comment: あっているかあっていないかは、質問者さんがどのような仕様を考えているかに依存するので、答えにくいです。代わりに、上手く動いていない部分を見つけたらそこについて別の質問を投稿するようにしてみたり、あっているかどうか確認するにはどうすれば良いか別途質問するようにしてみてください :)